# Order By on a modified Entity Framework object

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, sql-order-by

I'm getting an Entity Framework object collection from my Products table called oProducts.  I am looping through the collection and setting the Quantity field from a separate function.  Before I write out a display of the objects in HTML, I want to sort them by the Quantity.  So, I am using LINQ to create a new collection and try to order from the object collection that I just modified.  The modified values are definitely in the object collection and output properly, but the sort ordering isn't working on the modified field.  Does anyone know what I'm overlooking or a better way to attempt this?

```
Dim oProducts = From p in ctx.Products _
                Where p.Active = True _
                Select p

For Each prod in oProducts
    prod.Quantity = GetQuantity(prod.ProductID)
Next

Dim oOrderedProducts = From p in oProducts _
                       Order By p.Quantity Ascending _
                       Select p

For Each prod in oOrderedProducts
    Response.Write(prod.Quantity.ToString())
    '*** The Quantities are stored in the collection properly but it doesn't order by the Quantity field.
Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There a few things you need to remember:

1. Doing `From p in ctx.Products _` will *always* select from the database.
2. LINQ is lazy. It will not perform the database select until you iterate, and if you iterate twice, it will do the database select twice.
3. How data read from the database is combined with data already in the `ObjectContext` will vary based on the `MergeOption` of the query you execute. But it will always happen *after* the SQL is executed.

With those ideas in mind, let's consider your code:

This bit (1) creates an `IQueryable<Product>` which can be used as a basis for iteration or defining other queries. Note that it does not actually execute a database query.

```
Dim oProducts = From p in ctx.Products _  // (1)
                Where p.Active = True _
                Select p
```

The next bit (2) iterates the IQueryable defined above.

```
For Each prod in oProducts                          // (2)
    prod.Quantity = GetQuantity(prod.ProductID)
Next
```

Doing so causes a selection from the database. Inside the loop, you mutate the object that's returned. In LINQ to Objects, this would have *no effect whatsoever,* because the next time you iterated the IQueryable it would be executed anew. However, Entity objects are special. Mutating them marks the entity is changed on the context. Calling `SaveChanges()` later would save those modifications to the database.

It's important to note, however, that you have not changed the `IQueryable` variable `oProducts` *at all* by doing this. It is still a reference to a query which will be executed every time it is iterated. *It is not a list.* If you want a list, you need to call `ToList()` or `ToArray()`.

The following query (3) creates a new IQueryable based on the original `oProducts`. When iterated, this will produce new SQL which does much the same as the original query, except for the ordering you've added. Again, `oProducts` is a query, not a list.

```
Dim oOrderedProducts = From p in oProducts _                 // 3
                       Order By p.Quantity Ascending _
                       Select p
```

Finally, your code executes a new database query based on the IQueryable you defined above. As it executes this query, it merges the information retrieved from the database with the knowledge about the mutation you did above from the object context. Because the ordering is based on the query you defined, it is performed on the database server, using information in the database. Because information from the database is merged with information from the object context, you still see the mutation you performed on the data above, in (2).

```
For Each prod in oOrderedProducts                        
    Response.Write(prod.Quantity.ToString())
    '*** The Quantities are stored in the collection properly but it doesn't order by the Quantity field.
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the 3 consecutive LINQ expressions, combine them into one, using projection, either into an anonymous type (as I did here) or a real one.
This, below, should work

```
var oProducts = From p in ctx.Products
                Where p.Active == True
                orderby p.Quantity Ascending
                select new 
                {
                    Quantity = GetQuantity(p.ProductID)
                    // ... assign other properties too
                }

foreach ( var prod in oProducts )
{
  // do your output
}
```

Comment: You have the same problem here as Jay does. LINQ to Entities won't know how to translate `GetQuantity` into SQL, so this will produce a runtime error.

Comment: ahhh you're right - my mistake, yes you would need to rethink how to write the LINQ where/select so it can hit the db successfully, I overlooked the fact that the orderby was on the same variable as I was trying to set in the projection

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Dim oProducts = From p in ctx.Products _
                Where p.Active = True _
                Select p

For Each prod in oProducts
    prod.Quantity = GetQuantity(prod.ProductID)
Next

Dim oOrderedProducts = oProducts.OrderBy(Function(p) p.Quantity)
```

Comment: This code would produce a runtime error, because LINQ to Entities will not be able to translate `GetQuantity`. One way around that would be to call `AsEnumerable()` first.

Comment: Uh, yes, failed to register L2E; was thinking Linq To Sql. Now, what happens if you call ToList() or ToArray when creating oProducts?

Comment: Then it would work. *Why* it would work, though, is more complicated than translation to SQL; I explain this in my answer.